# how to call the a rest api using JWT in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-core-webapi, jwt

i have created one web api with jwt token based authentication in webapi. i want to call the rest api in the html page with angular js $http. i tried but its showing request failed .im getting response from the postman tool but in the webpage.dont know how to pass the bearer token in the header.

postman request

```
GET /api/mp/dashboard HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:55417
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAxLzA0L3htbGRzaWctbW9yZSNobWFjLXNoYTI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy54bWxzb2FwLm9yZy93cy8yMDA1LzA1L2lkZW50aXR5L2NsYWltcy9uYW1lIjoiQWRtaW4iLCJleHAiOjE1NjA5NDcyMzMsImlzcyI6Im15c2l0ZS5jb20iLCJhdWQiOiJteXNpdGUuY29tIn0.SMTy2H5vmWWUgCytHEHfT847ipE2hCzk0wvP2Of60Uk
```

angular js code

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {                 
    $http.get("http://ip_address:3393/api/mp/dashboard", {
        headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAxLzA0L3htbGRzaWctbW9yZSNobWFjLXNoYTI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy54bWxzb2FwLm9yZy93cy8yMDA1LzA1L2lkZW50aXR5L2NsYWltcy9uYW1lIjoiQWRtaW4iLCJleHAiOjE1NjA5NDcyMzMsImlzcyI6Im15c2l0ZS5jb20iLCJhdWQiOiJteXNpdGUuY29tIn0.SMTy2H5vmWWUgCytHEHfT847ipE2hCzk0wvP2Of60Uk' }
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
        $scope.fridgetemp = $scope.myWelcome.fridge_temp;       
    });
});
```

Comment: Just to be sure, did you check in the backend if the header is arriving or not? Maybe it *is* arriving but there is any other problem.

Comment: but in the post man tool its working with only single header bearer authentication header.while its running in postman , it should run in angular js code also.

Comment: Just chek CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing) permissions settings in your api.
E.g api running on same system on different port and UI running on different port, browser will block XHR requests.

Comment: i got it . sorry i was not using correct api .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This Http get call, for headers you have to pass a field in the object called **Content-Type : 'application/json'** along with Authorization

```
$http({
            method: "GET",
            url: 'http://ip_address:3393/api/mp/dashboard',
            headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAxLzA0L3htbGRzaWctbW9yZSNobWFjLXNoYTI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy54bWxzb2FwLm9yZy93cy8yMDA1LzA1L2lkZW50aXR5L2NsYWltcy9uYW1lIjoiQWRtaW4iLCJleHAiOjE1NjA5NDcyMzMsImlzcyI6Im15c2l0ZS5jb20iLCJhdWQiOiJteXNpdGUuY29tIn0.SMTy2H5vmWWUgCytHEHfT847ipE2hCzk0wvP2Of60Uk'
            },
            data: '' //this field depends on coder.
        })
        .then(function (response) {
                //your success result code handling 
            },
            function (error) {
              //your error handling code
                }
            });
```